# Pinterest API - Timeout

Tags: javascript, pinterest

Has anyone experienced the "Trying to login before initializing." error?

It seems like there is a limit to the number of calls you can make to the API but I have not hit the 1000 per hour by any means.

This even occurs after I authenticate once.  Once I refresh the page, I get the message above.  I end up waiting a little bit (usually a few mins) then I can authenticate again.

I would like this to go away or at least save the authentication within a cookie or something like that.

Can anyone lead me in the right direction?

Appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: Initializing with this code:  

`<script>
    window.pAsyncInit = function() {
        PDK.init({
            appId: "xxxxxxxxx", // Change this 
            cookie: true });
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, pjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//assets.pinterest.com/sdk/sdk.js";
        pjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, pjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'pinterest-jssdk'));
    
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting that same error message when setting `appId` to null or undefined in `PDK.init`. Maybe you are doing the init logic before the actual value is assigned.

I'd recommend using environment variables to keep the App ID outside of your code and inject it at build time, similar to how Create React App does it: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-custom-environment-variables